# What’s the explanation on why the outlets wires are on the same coils?

Tags: transformer, transformerless

Working on fixing a once upon a time good soldering station so I thought.

Inside the soldering station there’s two transformers, first one for the soldering iron that has an primary of 115 V and outputs of 12 / 24 / 7 V.
The second transformer is for the desoldering iron, vacuum pump, control board also (I assume) in which its primary is also 115 V and outputs are 12.5 / 25 / 7 V and an additional 24 V.

After dissecting the outlet side of the transformer and started unwinding the coil, I realized they basically had 3 transformer in one. What I’m trying to understand is why they have it wired the way they do.

Wire diagram labeled on transformer:

- 12.5V (red-brown)2A
- 25V (red-black)2A
- 7V (red-orange).7A
- 24V (green-green)1A

[image]

Note: this all is all wired to a plug that goes directly to the PCB board. First unwind was the 24V (green-green) 1A in .5mm wire. Second unwind was the orange which was .2mm wire got to the end where the red was soldered to the other end. Next was the brown got to the other end and the black was soldered to the end of the coil.

Red obviously being the common wire I can see and sort of understand that one. The black and brown I’m trying to understand, is because they have it wound for 25V and the 12.5V is coming from that?

Comment: Are these line-frequency transformers, flyback transformers, or standard SMPS transformers? Transformers of all types are frequently custom-made for applications; it's not too expensive when you're talking about making millions of units.

Comment: Both transformers are gonski?

Comment: Do you know the transformer is bad?

Comment: @Hearth it’s a power transformer. I can give you the part number from the original one if you’d like to take a look. PT-036 (SL-928) comes up under Soony rung lol.

Comment: @MiNiMe no just the one is toast

Comment: @winny yes it’s fried, I’ll add a picture

Comment: Count the turns as you unwind it and make a new one using the same core? Bobbin and tape you probably need too.

Comment: That’s my plan as of right now lol. i actually have a spare transformer that has the same size bobbin and what not so I got lucky there

Comment: I've tried to salvage the question for you. Still not sure if it is OK.

Comment: Well apparently I’m dumb didn’t realize I had already posted a question

Answer (score 2):

Mains frequency transformers are very often custom (in terms of units sold).

Even in an order of a few hundred you can get exactly what you want, at a lower price point than going to a COTS transformer and it will have safety agency markings if the shop is approved.

In your case, you probably will have to combine available mains frequency transformers to get what you need. Note that you can add and buck windings to get various voltages. You could also investigate finding a donor 'parts' carcass to cannibalize.

It's unusual for such transformers to go bad and your olefactory senses should yield a strong indication if that has happened. Perhaps a fuse has gone. Some are protected by a fuse hidden under the tape wrap which makes it a UL Class 2 effectively (or elsewhere where you may have missed it) and replacing the fuse with the exact type and rating could restore it. Sometimes the repetitive jolts from charging caps etc. can cause a fuse to eventually fail even without a fault in the transformer itself.

There were once transformer "kits" available which had a pre-wound primary suitable for mains voltage(s), and which you could make your own secondary windings for whatever voltages you wanted (of the order of a half a volt or volt per turn, so not many turns for the voltages we're talking about), but I've not seen them on offer for many years. Maplin, for example, had them. That incarnation of Maplin was defunct as of 2018.

Comment: And may I add the input winding is still perfectly fine, with that being said do you think it could be possible to remove the secondary winding and make my own? Maybe unwind and count to see how they have done things?

Comment: Rare that the much thicker wire of the secondaries would fail. Maybe there is a bad connection to the magnet wire, I guess I what you suggest might be possible, depending on the construction, but I’d be on the lookout for an easier fix before butchering it badly.

Comment: I went ahead and unwound everynting and sure enough the spool for the 24v was split. After looking at it I don’t believe re spooling the secondary is to difficult. I have .5mm magnet wire I’d just need to order the .2mm. Most difficult thing would be making sure I spool the correct amount.

Comment: @JakeFanthorp If you count the turns on any one winding, it should be possible to calculate the turns the other windings should have. It would be better to count the turns on all windings, though. It would be best to re-wind all windings, not just one; a secondary failure without a primary failure is a little strange, barring mechanical damage. You will also need some insulating tape to put between the primary and secondary, for isolation purposes. *This is a safety concern*; do not skimp on the insulating tape.

Comment: Correct I have counted the turns. I also have insulating tape but the way this one was made is the 2 bobbins actually go inside a sleeve with an insulator built into the sleeve. Maybe I’m just thinking about what they did wrong so maybe you can help me understand better. Output voltages and wiring- 12.5v (red-brown)2A, 25v(red-black) 7v

Comment: Correct I have counted the turns. I also have insulating tape but the way this one was made is the 2 bobbins actually go inside a sleeve with an insulator built into the sleeve. Maybe I’m just thinking about what they did wrong so maybe you can help me understand better. Output voltages and wiring- 12.5v (red-brown)2A, 25v(red-black)2A 7v(red-orange).7A 24v(green-green). Obviously red being common. When I unwound the transformer the brown and black wires were on the same spool along with the red and orange. Since brown is 12.5v is it pulling from the 25v? Or am I missing something

Comment: I once made a Maplin transformer.  It worked, but hummed very loudly, as it's hard to get the windings tight enough when doing it by hand.

Comment: @SimonB I guess you could have lacquered the windings, but that would make it more permanent.